# Tableau LOD (i think)

Tags: tableau-api, calculation, tableau-desktop, level-of-detail

I am trying to create a visualisation where i can see where a product has passed 2 tests: test=overall **and** test=flash (these are part of the same column). then there is a column **result** which can be pass/fail. i want both of these tests to be pass and then i want to count the distinct products. I then want to include this figure in a dashboard that updates.

I think I want a LOD but not sure where to start. is this something i do in desktop or prep[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UzLk.png)

I am new to Tableau so LOD is something i am trying to get my head around

Answer (score 0):

Use the below calculation,

```
if {fixed [Device]: min([Result])}='fail' then False else TRUE end
```

Pull this field to filter shelf and select TRUE to get only devices which pass both tests

Comment: You need a closing curly brace before “then” to be syntactically valid. And could simplify since there is no need to use If, or return literal boolean expressions like True and False - since MIN() of a boolean condition already is a boolean expression

Comment: Even with those simplifications, I think this isn’t completely correct, looks like it filters to those devices that ever passed any test of any kind.

Comment: Not really, I created this assuming there will be two values pass and fail. So whenever there is a failed test this LOD will return fail and the condition will pass. Hence the if condition will return False if any of the test failed.

Comment: There are other tests, such as temperature, and a device could take a test multiple times, and have failed sometimes, and passed others

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t say how to treat devices that have both pass and fail entries for one of your tests. This expression tests whether a device has passed at least one overall test and at least one flash test. You could also use a version of this to define a set if you preferred

```
{ fixed [Device] : max([test] = “overall” and [Result] = “pass”) and
                   max([test] = “flash” and [Result] = “pass”) }
```

The key concept is that MIN() and MAX() operate on boolean arguments to return boolean values, treating True values and greater than False values. So MAX() tests whether the condition is **ever** satisfied; i.e. it returns true if the condition evaluates to true for at least one of the data records. Likewise, MIN() tests whether the condition is **always satisfied**; i.e. it returns true if the condition evaluates to true for every one of the data records.

If the condition ever evaluates to null, MIN() and MAX() ignore null values just like all other aggregation functions. So if that is an issue in your case, you can use IFNULL() around your expression to provide a default value.